# Определение ближайших координатных точек

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как определить ближайшие координатные точки при вводе курсора мышки в области (зеленую или желтую), для того что бы отрисовать второй контур и залить его другим цветом.
Координаты лежат в массиве.
`Points = [{x:0,y:0},....];`
[image: example]

Comment: Где код? Или с нуля надо написать?

Comment: Если это canvas. Формула для расстояния: ((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)^(0.5). [Как рисовать треугольник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

Если рисуете в `canvas`-е, то могу предложить такой алгоритм, очень важно чтобы изначально заданных точек было как минимум 2:

```js
//DEFINE INPUT, OBJECTS AND SECONDARY FUNCTIONS
const dots = [{x: 100, y: 50}, {x: 250, y: 50}, {x: 250, y: 150}, {x: 100, y: 100}];
const staticObjects = [];
const dynamicObjects = [];

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

class FilledPolygon {  
  constructor(dots, fillColor) {
    this.dots = dots;
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
  }
  
  draw() {
    const path = new Path2D();
    const firstDot = this.dots[0];
  
    this.dots.forEach(dot => path.lineTo(dot.x, dot.y));

    path.lineTo(firstDot.x, firstDot.y);

    context.fillStyle = this.fillColor;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.fill(path);
    context.stroke(path);
  }
}

class CornerCircle {
  constructor(center) {
    this.center = center;
  }
  
  draw() {
    const path = new Path2D();
    path.arc(this.center.x, this.center.y, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.stroke(path);
  }
}

const dist = (dot1, dot2) => Math.sqrt((dot2.x - dot1.x)**2 + (dot2.y - dot1.y)**2);

const findNearestDots = (dots, needDot) => {
  const nearestDots = [
    {
      distanceToNeedDot: Infinity,
      self: null
    },
    {
      distanceToNeedDot: Infinity,
      self: null
    },
  ];
  
  dots.forEach(dot => {
    const distanceToNeedDot = dist(dot, needDot);
    
    if (distanceToNeedDot < nearestDots[0].distanceToNeedDot) {
      
      [nearestDots[0], nearestDots[1]] = [nearestDots[1], nearestDots[0]];
      
      nearestDots[0].distanceToNeedDot = distanceToNeedDot;
      nearestDots[0].self = dot;
      return;
    }
    
    if (distanceToNeedDot < nearestDots[1].distanceToNeedDot) {
      nearestDots[1].distanceToNeedDot = distanceToNeedDot;
      nearestDots[1].self = dot;
      return;
    }
  });
  
  return nearestDots.map(dot => dot.self);
}

//STATIC OBJECTS
staticObjects.push(new FilledPolygon(dots, 'lightgreen'));
dots.forEach((dot, i) => staticObjects.push(new CornerCircle(dot)));

//UPDATE STATE LOGIC
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const mouseDot = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
  
  const [nearestDot1, nearestDot2] = findNearestDots(dots, mouseDot);
  
  dynamicObjects[0] = new FilledPolygon([nearestDot1, nearestDot2, mouseDot], 'yellow');
  dynamicObjects[1] = new CornerCircle(mouseDot);
});


//DRAW LOGIC
const draw = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  staticObjects.forEach(staticObject => staticObject.draw());
  dynamicObjects.forEach(dynamicObject => dynamicObject.draw());
}

draw();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пример хороший но немного не то что нужно. Нужно не отрисовать желтый треугольник(он уже нарисован был), конкретно нужно при вводе мышки в область (формально их 2, я изобразил фигуры разными цветами на рисунке для понимания, а так это хаотичные фигуры из линий), к примеру в зеленую определить что это за фигура продублировать ее и залить другим цветом как-то так...

Comment: Я ничего не понял, если честно. У вас есть 2 фигуры, труеугольник и четырёхугольник. Что должно произойти, когда курсор например в треугольнике?

Comment: Нужно узнать координаты точек этого треугольника, и залить его цветом

Comment: Каким цветом надо залить? И как надо узнать, какой именно треугольник вам нужен, если у вас просто массив точек. Это может быть и пятиугольником. У вас данные только о точках, нет информации о линиях их соединяющих

Comment: Цвет не важен, любой. Вот в этом вся и загвоздка, что из этого массива точек нужно узнать где курсор находится будь то треугольник или много угольник

Comment: Окей, вопрос с линиями остаётся открытым

Comment: Это впринципе невозможно, разбросанные по плоскости точки можно соединять как вздумается. Любые 3 не совпадающие точки, которые не находятся на одной прямой можно соединить как треугольник. Если точек 4 то я уже могу их соединить как четырехугольник или как 2 треугольника или как 4 треугольника. Нельзя просто взять и сказать, что тут должен был быть треугльник :)

Comment: Ну тут немного массив я не верно указал Каждая линия имеет начало и конец(он же начало следующей линии) [{x1,y1,x2,y2},{....}]

Comment: Только писал о том что в массиве точки дожны быть чётко упорядочены) Тогда почему у вас на картинке не соединены точкки 1 и 2?

Comment: А, стоп. Я не заметил. Вам даны не массив точек, а массив линий? Или всё же упорядоченные точки, которые по прядку соединяются?

Comment: Ну вообще скорее это массив линий вы правы, изначально они у меня соединяются по порядку(т.к это обычно 4 линии в виде прямоугольника), но далее уже внутри этого прямоугольника могут появится линии которые его и разбивают так сказать на треугольники, многоугольники и т.д

Comment: Офигеть, даже так))) Вам скорее надо задать вопрос на https://math.stackexchange.com/, по крайней мере мне так кажется) Вам нужен алгоритм поиска минимальных фигур образующихся пересечением отрезков. Если сам что-то придумаю то отпишусь)